# Blackberry 10 custom mediaplayer library in BB10 Cascades

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, cascade

Hi I am developing an application to play live stream audio using Blackberry 10 Cascades. And for this now I am using Mediaplayer .But I want to do the rewind operation in live streaming, that is I want to save the streaming contents in to file and switch between these file to play the audio without any interruption. I want to know is there any library available for doing this?. Or weather this can be done by the Mediaplayer itself?

Comment: How far back do you want to rewind? You should consider either storing data in memory. Otherwise most of the time you will be writing data to the file for no purpose, and wearing out the flash.

Comment: I would like to rewind the live stream up to 10 mins.